# Grails Dependencies not Added as Libraries to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am running into an issue when I import a Grails project into IntelliJ IDEA. None of the dependencies are added as libraries. Everything out there says that Tools -> Grails -> Synchronize Grails Settings should be sufficient to configure the project. However, when I run that command, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\Users\req88100\.gvm\grails\2.4.4 -Dbase.dir=C:\Users\req88100\Projects\COI_2.4.4 "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\Users\req88100\.gvm\grails\2.4.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Users\req88100\.gvm\grails\2.4.4\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.7.jar;C:\Users\req88100\.gvm\grails\2.4.4\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.4.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\Users\req88100\.gvm\grails\2.4.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf "idea-print-project-settings -plain-output"
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
|Script 'IdeaPrintProjectSettings' not found, did you mean:
   1) SetProxy_
   2) CreateMultiProjectBuild_
   3) Interactive
   4) ClearProxy_
   5) UrlMappingsReport
Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

I can manually add the jars to the module as libraries, but this is cumbersome. Without it, none of the code completion works correctly. That project is working correctly because `grails run-app` runs just fine.

This is with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 on Windows 7 and several different version of Grails 2.x.x. I've tried the command manually is both Cygwin and with a standard Windows Command Prompt. Both yield that same results as IntelliJ IDEA.

There are very few Google results for either `idea-print-project-settings` or `IdeaPrintProjectSettings`. I am not sure where this script is supposed to come from.

How do I configure IntelliJ IDEA to properly pull the libraries into the module configuration?

Comment: Have you tried `Run Grails target -> clean-all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding how Grails resolves Gant scripts really helps:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html

> Grails searches in the following directories for Gant scripts to execute:
>
> - USER_HOME/.grails/scripts
> - PROJECT_HOME/scripts
> - PROJECT_HOME/plugins/*/scripts
> - GRAILS_HOME/scripts

The problem seems that IntelliJ IDEA is automagically providing this Gant script, but putting the script in the wrong spot.

Using VisualVM, here are the user directories:

```
user.dir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%
user.home=\\SOME\network\drive\%USERNAME%
```

So even though Cygwin, and so it seems IntelliJ IDEA, treats `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` as the home directory, the Windows Group Policy maps it to a network share and Java uses this value as `user.home`.

Looking in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.grails\scripts`, I was able to find the script. I copied it to `\\SOME\network\drive\%USERNAME%\.grails\scripts` and then Grails recognized the script and IntelliJ IDEA was able to configure itself properly.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across with this issue on Windows 10 and I was finally able to solve it after a few attempts. I just did the following:

1. Searched for the `IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy` script.
2. Copied it to my actual Grails scripts directory that was something like `...\Grails2.2.2\scripts` or whatever IntelliJ was pointing to at the time.
3. Synchronized my Grails projects again.

The issue here, as it was previously pointed out, is that IntelliJ context for Grails is looking for this script in another directory. In my case, IntelliJ was looking in the Grails cache.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by creating a scripts directory in `usernamefolder/.grails/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the "Error executing script IdeaPrintProjectSettings:" inside intellij try this on linux:

1. go to command prompt in home directory cd to project root directory
   (e.g., cd $HOME/IdeaProjects/Simulator01)
2. run the 'grails' command
3. at the prompt once at the grails prompt run "refresh-dependencies"
   and hit [ENTER]
4. once that completes without error you should be able
   to do the next step:
5. at the grails prompt run 'idea-print-project-settings' and get the output without error.

Now try the project rebuild in intellij, might have to invalidate cache first.

Good luck,
David

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy in 
USER-HOME.grails\scripts\IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy (i'm using IDEA version2016.3)
OR 
USER-HOME.grails\IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy
It depends on your IDEA version.

(sorry I don't know how to attach this file in stackoverflow for someone who needs it).